# Deriving spherical pendulum equations with an Applied torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, torque

I'm and electrical engineer and I'm trying to derive a state space model for a spherical pendulum with an applied torque to the system, not energy. So if I understand correctly I can't apply the Lagrange equation $L = T - V$ as the input is torque, not energy. Every example I see on the web uses this equation. Can anybody help me? As I'm way out of my league here.
The applied torque has component on both angles.